# How to get a value you got from onclick event function to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My problem is I have an HTML object -> `<button></button>` and inside this button is an onclick 
event that calls a function that that gets a variable from the location where the button is:

```
<button onclick="myFunction(myVariable)"></button>
```

However I want to use myVariable in myFunction().
I already tried something like this:

```
function myFunction(myVariable){
   alert(myVariable);
}
```

But I only get objecthtmlbuttonelement as alert..

Hope you can help me guys, thanks!

//for better understanding i'll add my code in:

```
function displayProducts(){
    //var sum = 0; 
    sum = 0;
        db.transaction(function(tx){
            tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM products",[], function(tx,results){
                len = results.rows.length;
                var stuff = "<div id='products'>";

                for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
                    var products_all = results.rows.item(i).p_name; //the variable
                    var price = results.rows.item(i).price;
                    if(i%4==0){
                        stuff += "<br/>";
                    }
                    var izdelki = "<div id='izpis_izdelkov'>";

                    //here's the button element
                    stuff += "<button class='pivo'  id='"+products_all+"' onclick='Calculate("+products_all+");' name='"+products_all+"' value='"+price+"'>"+products_all+'</button>';


                }
                $('#stuff').html(stuff + "</div>");
                $('#izd').html(izdelki + "</div>");
            });
        });
    }
```

//the function I want to use the variable

```
function Calculate(products_all){
    alert(products_all);
}
```

Comment: What does the variable hold? And is it a global variable? If it's global, you want to remove teh `myVariable` parameter from the `myFunction`

Comment: I don't see an reference to the variable you are trying to pass.

Comment: Can you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) reproducing this problem?

Comment: We don't need an off-site demo. We need complete information directly in the question.

Comment: when registering a callback with `onclick` the first Parameter will be the event-target. In this case the `button`. So write: `onclick="myFunction(this, myVariable)"`. And then: `function myFunction(button, myVariableFromOnClick) {}`.

Comment: @phylax: No, only if you actually name it `event` for the event object. The first parameter will be whatever you define it as. *(There is more complexity than that, but it's beyond the question)*

Comment: @cookiemonster That's true, but by attempting to reproduce what it likely a simple oversight, the OP may be able to solve the problem him/her self.

Comment: As you're using jQuery, did you ever consider just using jQuery, as in *using jQuery* to create the elements and the event handlers instead of strings with inline javascript ?

Comment: I'm very fresh at all this stuff so i'm using a little of everything..

Comment: Inline handlers only have access to global variables, the `event` parameter, and any property that appears directly on the element bound or on the `document`. Local vars will not show up. You should create the element using DOM methods, and bind the handler directly, though you'll need to deal with a variable scope issue.

Comment: @phylax getting the same result.. objecthtmlbuttonelement

Comment: `onclick='Calculate(\""+products_all+"\");'`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<button onclick="myFunction(myVariable)"></button>

function myFunction(varriableFunc){
   alert(varriableFunc);
alert(myVariable);
}
```

You are passing tha variable "myVariable" how function param, this form the parameter has the same valuw from the "myVariable".

If you want use "myVariable" inside the function it need to a global variable. the better way is pass values how parameters.

---

In your new code you put

```
for (var i=0; i<len; i++){
                    var products_all =
```

This way the variable products_all exists only in the for context. Try declare it how a global variable.

```
var products_all = 0;
```

in the begin of the tag ;

You wont need pass products_all to function how parameter, you will can use it all the script. but becarefull with this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ''.

```
<button onclick="myFunction('myVariable')"></button>
```

This also works here:

```
<script>
myVariable = "lol";

function myFunction(myVariable){
   alert(myVariable);
}
</script>

<button onclick="myFunction(myVariable)"></button>
```

Comment: Based on the edit to the question, the `''` answer here seems to be exactly what the poster was looking for -- why are people downvoting it?

Comment: I get the variable into the function when calling the function, not the other way. look the code up there..

Comment: @Live: Based on your code, you have a single `Calculate()` function that you want to pass a different string value to based on which button was clicked. So, you want one button to have `onclick="Calculate('a')"` and another to have `onclick="Calculate('b')"`, so that in `Calculate()`, the `products_all` variable will be 'a' or 'b' depending on what button was clicked.

Comment: @Live - That just means you need to change the string construction to `onclick='Calculate('"+products_all+"');' `

Comment: -1 your first example passes a string. It doesn't reference a variable. The second is effectively what he's already doing, so it isn't going to solve anything.

Comment: @cookiemonster: Passing a string is exactly what the questioner wanted; the question was just not clear about that.

Comment: @cookiemonster - The button is constructed in code, using a string from `.name` so it is accurate, even if the readability of the post is very poor.

Comment: I did not had the code on the original post so I had no way of knowing this :) But you are right.

Comment: @RussellZahniser: Passing a quoted version of the variable is not what he wanted.

Comment: @cookiemonster could you please make me an example of what you mean it's right..?

Comment: I don't know what the data is. But if it is indeed a string, then just concatenate it into the `Calculate` call, but with quotes around it.

Comment: ...Patrick Q left a comment under your question that shows how.

Comment: @TravisJ: Not sure what you mean. The fact that the value it comes from a property doesn't make this answer accurate. All he did was quote the variable name that was in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

As a work around i'd add the variable's value as a data attribute to the button and pass `this` as argument to handler function:

```
stuff += "<button class='pivo'  id='"+products_all+"' onclick='Calculate(this);' name='"+products_all+"' value='"+price+"' data-value='"+products_all+"'>"+products_all+"</button>";
```

and access the data attribute in the function

```
function Calculate(btn){
        alert($(btn).attr('data-value')); //
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure they're strings?

Comment: @cookiemonster `var products_all = results.rows.item(i).p_name;`

Comment: @TravisJ: I saw that. But how do we know that's a string? If it is, then we can just do it without using data attrs.

Comment: @cookiemonster - Pretty strongly implied it is a string. The data- would be overkill though.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to insert quotes around the value of `products_all` in the `onclick` attribute. Then it will be clear that you are passing a string with that value, rather than trying to reference a (nonexistent) variable with that name:

```
stuff += "<button onclick='Calculate(\"" + products_all + "\">";
```

... compared to your code doing just:

```
stuff += "<button onclick='Calculate(" + products_all + ">";
```

If `products_all` has values "a", "b", and "c", then your version will generate:

```
<button onclick='Calculate(a)'>
<button onclick='Calculate(b)'>
<button onclick='Calculate(c)'>
```

... which references undefined variables named `a`, `b`, and `c`. The altered version will generate:

```
<button onclick='Calculate("a")'>
<button onclick='Calculate("b")'>
<button onclick='Calculate("c")'>
```

... so that you are passing one of the string values "a", "b", or "c" to the `post_all` variable inside `Calculate()`.